# Problems with C pointers

Tags: c, pointers, char

So I've been having trouble just understanding pointers in C. My problem is how to make char * find_ch_ptr return a char*. I've also been getting cast problems all over the place. If there is something wrong in here, can you please explain it fully?

```
/*
 * Return a pointer to the first occurrence of <ch> in <string>,
 * or NULL if the <ch> is not in <string>.
 *****
 * YOU MAY *NOT* USE INTEGERS OR ARRAY INDEXING.
 *****
 */
char *find_ch_ptr(char *string, char ch) {
        char * point = (char*)(string + 0);
        char * c = &ch;
        while(point != '\0') {
                if(point == c) return (char*)point;
                else *point++;
        }
        return (char*)point;    // placeholder
}
```

Comment: You don't need to cast `char*` to `char*`.

Comment: You don't need any of the casts, and `else *point++` is also ok like `else point++;`

Comment: you dont mean *point++ you mean point++

Comment: @pm100; Effect will be same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compare the character currently pointed to by `point` you need to dereference `point` with the `*` operator like this

```
while (*point != '\0')
```

Then you want to compare the character that you are searching for but you are doing it the wrong way too.

You are comparing the address of the variable `ch` to the address currently `point` points to, that is wrong you need

```
if (*point == ch)
```

instead.

Answer (score 5):

```
while(point != '\0')
```

should be

```
while(*point != '\0')
```

There are places where you need to dereference the pointer and you are not doing it.Like

```
while(*point != '\0')
{
  if(*point == ch)
  return point;
  else
  point ++;
}
```

PS: `point` is a pointer pointing to some valid memory location and the value stored in that location is got by dereferencing it `*point`

Comment: @Gopi; My bad! Of course he can return the address of the element of the passes string.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like [strchr()](https://www.thinkage.ca/english/gcos/expl/c/lib/strchr.html)

Usage:

```
#include <string.h>
ptr = strchr( s, c );
```

Comment: May be it's homework and they have to write their own function.

Comment: @iharob Especially so given the comment `YOU MAY *NOT* USE INTEGERS OR ARRAY INDEXING.`

Answer (score 2):

heres a working version of your code

Please tell you teacher that you got it from stack overflow

```
char *find_ch_ptr(char *string, char ch) {

        while(*string != '\0') {
                if(*string == ch) 
                   return string;
                else string++;
        }
        return (char*)0;
}
```

or the K&R way

```
while(*string && *string!=ch);
return str;
```

Comment: thank you! already fixed it from above comments though. Will do

Answer (score 2):

The while loop condition needed to be dereferenced before checking equivalence '\0'.

There is no need for the c variable, you can use the ch parameter directly for the check inside the while loop.

Here is a working example:

```
#include<stdio.h>

char *find_ch_ptr(char *string, char ch) {
    char *point = string;
    while(*point != '\0') {
            if(*point == ch)
            {
                    return point;
            }
            else
            {
                    point++;
            }
    }
    return point;    // placeholder
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    printf("%c\n", *find_ch_ptr("hello world", 'r'));
    return 0;
}
```